# unix diff --show-function-line truncates output

Tags: unix, diff, truncate

I'm working on diffing some ldif files where each section begins with "dn: leaf,branch3,branch2,branch1,root"  I would like the dn (distinguished name) for each section to be displayed, and the Unix diff utility has a feature to do that: --show-function-line=regular expression.  However, the diff util truncates the dn line in the output, which makes it harder to know the full path.

current command:

```
diff -U 0 --show-function-line="^dn\: .*" file1.ldif file2.ldif > deltas.txt
```

example output:

```
@@ -56 +56 @@ dn: administratorId=0,applicationName=pl
-previousLoginTime: 20120619180751Z
+previousLoginTime: 20120213173659Z
```

original dn:

```
dn: administratorId=0,applicationName=platform,nodeName=NODENAME
```

I would like the entire original line to be included in the output.  Is there a way to do this?

Thanks,
Rusty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by editing the source code and recompiling.

in src/context.c: print_context_function (FILE *out, char const *function)

changed line:

```
for (j = i; j < i + 40 && function[j] != '\n'; j++)
```

to

```
for (j = i; j < i + 100 && function[j] != '\n'; j++)
```

The "40" was limiting the number of characters output to 40, so I increased it to 100, which should be large enough for my needs.  That check could probably be omitted entirely, and let it just check for function[j] != '\n', but I decided to leave it as is.